# Android Fragment Not Calling Code in onStart()

Tags: android

I am making a consecutive alarm app that allows the user to set multiple alarms in one single "consecutive alarm." Each of the single alarms are stored in an ArrayList. I'm trying to make it so that when the user closes the app, the UI of the alarms that were set will show back up when they reopen the app. When android calls onStart(), it does not read the code after onStart() or I would know because I have logs within the code. What's wrong with it?

```
    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.e("asdfasdf", "onStart() called");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("AlarmDataBase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int toLoadSize = sharedPreferences.getInt("arraySize", 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < toLoadSize; i++) {
        ConsecAlarm toAdd = new ConsecAlarm();
        toAdd.setFromHour(sharedPreferences.getInt(i + "fromHour", 7));
        toAdd.setFromMinute(sharedPreferences.getInt(i + "fromMintue", 20));
        toAdd.setFromAM(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(i + "fromAM", true));
        toAdd.setToHour(sharedPreferences.getInt(i + "toHour", 7));
        toAdd.setToMinute(sharedPreferences.getInt(i + "toMinute", 30));
        toAdd.setToAM(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(i + "toAM", true));
        toAdd.setInterval(sharedPreferences.getInt(i + "interval", 5));
        int numAlarms = sharedPreferences.getInt(i + "numAlarms", 3);
        toAdd.setNumAlarms(numAlarms);
        for (int j = 0; j < numAlarms; j++) {
            toAdd.addAlarmHour(sharedPreferences.getInt(i + "alarmHour" + j, 0));
            toAdd.addAlarmMin(sharedPreferences.getInt(i + "alarmMin" + j, 0));
            Log.e("asdfasdf", toAdd.getAlarmHour(i) + ":" + toAdd.getAlarmMin(i) + " loaded");
        }
        mConsecAlarms.add(toAdd);
    }
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e("asdfasdf", "onStop() called");
    Collections.sort(mConsecAlarms, new Comparator<ConsecAlarm>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ConsecAlarm o1, ConsecAlarm o2) {
            return o1.getToHour() - o2.getToHour();
        }
    });
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("AlarmDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    int toSaveSize = mConsecAlarms.size();
    editor.putInt("arraySize", toSaveSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < toSaveSize; i++) {
        editor.putInt(i + "fromHour", mConsecAlarms.get(i).getFromHour());
        editor.putInt(i + "fromMinute", mConsecAlarms.get(i).getFromMinute());
        editor.putBoolean(i + "fromAM", mConsecAlarms.get(i).isFromAM());
        editor.putInt(i + "toHour", mConsecAlarms.get(i).getToHour());
        editor.putInt(i + "toMinute", mConsecAlarms.get(i).getToMinute());
        editor.putBoolean(i + "toAM", mConsecAlarms.get(i).isToAM());
        editor.putInt(i + "interval", mConsecAlarms.get(i).getInterval());
        int numAlarms = mConsecAlarms.get(i).getNumAlarms();
        editor.putInt(i + "numAlarms", numAlarms);
        for (int j = 0; j < numAlarms; j++) {
            editor.putInt(i + "alarmHour" + j, mConsecAlarms.get(i).getAlarmHour(j));
            editor.putInt(i + "alarmMin" + j, mConsecAlarms.get(i).getAlarmMin(j));
            Log.e("asdfasdf", mConsecAlarms.get(i).getAlarmHour(j) + ":" + mConsecAlarms.get(i).getAlarmMin(j) + " saved");
        }
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you submit the fragment? It is called after you submit it

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: what you mean by submit. . . ??